# How to specify which env_file is used in docker-compose via command line

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up a `docker-compose` file in a generic way so that I can create multiple shards of a database on one or more servers.

The options that would change between containers are:

1. container_name
2. volumes
3. env_file
4. ports
5. expose

So I want a generic `docker-compose.yml` file like the one below, except I don't know how I can set the `env_file` directive via command-line, something like

```
docker-compose up --build --env-file="path/to/shard1.env"
docker-compose up --build --env-file="path/to/shard2.env"
```

Is this possible, or am I going about this the wrong way?

```
version: "3"
services:
  shard:
    build: 
        context: ./database
    container_name: "${SHARD_NAME}"
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
        - "${SHARD_DIRECTORY}:/database"
    env_file: 
      - "${ENV_FILE}"
    ports:
      - "${PORT}:8000"
    expose:
      - "${PORT}"
    networks:
      - my_network
networks:
  my_network:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my terminal:

```
docker-compose --help
[...]
Options:
[...]
  --env-file PATH             Specify an alternate environment file
```

Tested successfully (passing an image name to the compose file...)

```
docker-compose --env-file .env-alt up -d
docker-compose --env-file .env-alt down
```

Wrong in your question command:

- Equal sign between value and option => it has to be removed
- Position of the option => it is a global option which must appear before command